# Java Invalid hex character: h

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I am using Java 8 with Spring and Maven.

I am trying to set up Push Notifications based on the [following tutorial](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59). I have them working perfectly for **Android**, using the following:

**NotificationServiceImpl.java**

```
private String sendAndroidPushNotification(String device_token, String topics, String title, String message)
        throws Exception {
    String pushMessage = null;
    if (device_token != null && !device_token.equals("null")) {
        pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" + title + "\",\"message\":\"" + message + "\"},\"to\":\""
                + device_token + "\"}";
    } else {
        pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" + title + "\",\"message\":\"" + message + "\"},\"to\": \"/topics/"
                + topics + "\"}";
    }
    // Create connection to send FCM Message request.
    URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    // Send FCM message content.
    OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(pushMessage.getBytes());

    return "Android Push Notification: " + conn.getResponseCode() + " " + conn.getResponseMessage() + " - " + pushMessage;
}
```

I am however, having an issue trying to set it up for **iOS**. I get the following error:

> ```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid hex character: h
>   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.charval(Utilities.java:132)
>   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.decodeHex(Utilities.java:119)
>   at com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification.<init>(EnhancedApnsNotification.java:77)
>   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:54)
>   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
>   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:45)
>   at com.jobs.spring.service.NotificationServiceImpl.sendIOSPushNotification(NotificationServiceImpl.java:90)
> ```

My code for **iOS** is as follows:

```
/**
 * import com.notnoop.apns.APNS; import com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService;
 * https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns.
 */
private static String sendIOSPushNotification(String device_token, String topics, String title, String message)
        throws Exception {
    ApnsService service = APNS.newService().withCert(PATH_TO_P12_CERT, CERT_PASSWORD).withSandboxDestination()
            .build();

    String payload = APNS.newPayload()
            // .customFields(map)
            .alertBody(title + " " + message).sound("default").build();

    service.push(topics, payload); // <<<<< line 90
    return "iOS Push Notification: " + title + " " + message;
}
```

As you can see, the error occurs as a result of the line of code on line 90.

```
service.push(topics, payload);
```

I think this is a result of the code being different from the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59), which is as follows:

```
service.push(DEVICE_TOKEN, payload);
```

I need my notification service to rather use a `topic` and not a `device token` (the client subscribes to a `topic`). This worked successfully for **Android** as you can see above.

**Question**

If anyone can shed some light on how I can resolve this **iOS** issue, I would appreciate the help.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I will add a little more info, because from the comments below (thanks for the help), I am told that the parameter should be a `devise token` and not a `topic`.

My problem is my client subscribes to a topic. This is business logic that I cannot change.

```
        let topics: string[] = [this.personModelLoggedIn.uid];
        const options: PushOptions = {
          android: {
            senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            sound: "true",
            vibrate: "true",
            topics: topics
          },
          ios: {
            senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            alert: "true",
            badge: true,
            sound: "true",
            topics: topics
          },
          windows: {}
        };
```

I see the [`com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService`](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/blob/master/src/main/java/com/notnoop/apns/ApnsService.java) receives a `Collection<String>` of devise tokens.

```
push(Collection<String> deviceTokens, String payload)
```

I will try put my `topic` `String` in a `Collection`, and see if that works.

Comment: Why the the down vote? Is this not a legitimate question?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What is kept in 'payload' variable?

Comment: *Invalid hex character: h* I would say you have to send a hex value but you send a string

Comment: I didn't downvote, but we don't know what the parameters are and the exception seems pretty clear. Looks like a job for your debugger

Comment: @Lemonov This is realy clear *String payload = APNS.newPayload()
            // .customFields(map)
            .alertBody(title + " " + message).sound("default").build();*

Comment: The parameters are as follows: `"hghbA5bPJBX1wICSLUsg3pRX2jt2"`, so `topic` is a `String`.

Comment: h<-- this is not hex value (same for rest) ghbA5bPJBX1wICSLUsg3pRX2jt2.   Function clearly needs hex values so string wont be accepted.

Comment: The first argument to `service.push` should be a device token - `topics` doesn't sound like it'll be a device token...

Comment: @Lemonov, thanks. Excuse my ignorance but, do I need to convert the `String` to a `hex` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [src code](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/blob/master/src/main/java/com/notnoop/apns/EnhancedApnsNotification.java#L58):

```
58     /** 
59      * The infinite future for the purposes of Apple expiry date 
60      */ 
61     public final static int MAXIMUM_EXPIRY = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
62 

63     /** 
64      * Constructs an instance of {@code ApnsNotification}. 
65      * 
66      * The message encodes the payload with a {@code UTF-8} encoding. 
67      * 
68      * @param dtoken    The Hex of the device token of the destination phone 
69      * @param payload   The payload message to be sent 
70      */ 
71     public EnhancedApnsNotification( 
72             int identifier, int expiryTime, 
73             String dtoken, String payload) { 
74         this.identifier = identifier; 
75         this.expiry = expiryTime; 
76         this.deviceToken = Utilities.decodeHex(dtoken); 
77         this.payload = Utilities.toUTF8Bytes(payload); 
78     }
```

the devicetoken must be hex encoded.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue for me. I converted the topic to hex. `public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
}`

Comment: @Richard I think you should better use the method `encodeHex` from the class `com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities`

Comment: `service.push(Utilities.encodeHex(topics.getBytes()), payload);`